# using nested ngFor to traverse two separate arrays

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm fairly new to ionic and angular and am having an issue in using *ngFor to print contents from two separate arrays.

I've defined these two arrays in the .ts file:

```
  public tagArray: any = ["Business", "Casual","Sales"];
  public contactArray: any = [
   [ //Business
    ['', 'John', '', 'Snow', 'Unemployed'],
    ['', 'Charles', '', 'Boyle', 'NYPD'],
    ['', 'Jim', '', 'Smith', 'Professor'],
    ['', 'Amy', '', 'Santiago', 'NYPD'],
    ['', 'Mike', '', 'Faust', 'Retired'],
    ['', 'Rosa', '', 'Diaz', 'NYPD'],
  ],
  [ //Casual
    ['', 'John', '', 'Cena', 'WWE'],
    ['', 'Raymond', '', 'Holt', 'NYPD'],
    ['', 'Mike', '', 'Galle', 'Professor'],
    ['', 'Jake', '', 'Peralta', 'NYPD'],
    ['', 'Amy', '', 'Santiago', 'NYPD'],
  ],
  [ //Sales
    ['', 'Mike', '', 'Ross', 'Lawyer'],
    ['', 'Terry', '', 'Jeffords', 'NYPD'],
    ['', 'Louis', '', 'Litt', 'Lawyer'],
  ]
];
```

I want to display a tag, and then all the contacts for that tag underneath it, and then the next tag, and so on.

However, when I try to display the tags and contents, it only does 3 contacts per tag (because there are 3 tags). I believe its using the same value for both the tag index and contact index. Here is the html code:

```
<ion-list-header *ngFor = "let att of tagArray; let tagidx = index">
  <h1>{{ att.h1 }}{{ tagArray[tagidx] }}</h1>

<ion-item-sliding *ngFor ="let att of contactArray;  let idx = index">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img src="">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2 id="name">{{att.h2}} {{contactArray[tagidx][idx][1] + ' ' + contactArray[tagidx][idx][3]}}</h2>
    <p id="company">{{att.p2}} {{contactArray[tagidx][idx][4]}}</p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options>
    <button ion-button color="light" icon-start>
      <ion-icon name="ios-more"></ion-icon>
      More
    </button>
    <button ion-button color="primary" icon-start>
      <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
      Text
    </button>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" icon-start>
      <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
      Call
    </button>
  </ion-item-options>

</ion-item-sliding>

</ion-list-header>
```

It prints them in the format I want it in, but it doesn't get all the contacts.
[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xopsl.jpg)

I've seen some examples of others using nested objects, however with the way data is stored in my application i'd prefer to use arrays instead. Any help on how I can display the tags and contacts properly would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having a strange mix of *ngFor and direct accessing via index. Also it's misleading when you use `att` in 2 different loops. Try it this way:

```
<ion-list-header *ngFor = "let tag of tagArray; let tagidx = index">
    <h1>{{ tag }}</h1>

    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor ="let contact of contactArray[tagIdx];  let idx = index">
        <ion-item>
           <ion-avatar item-start>
              <img src="">
                  </ion-avatar>
                      <h2 id="name">{{contact[1] + ' ' + contact[3]}}</h2>
                      <p id="company">{{contact[4]}}</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options>
            <button ion-button color="light" icon-start>
                <ion-icon name="ios-more"></ion-icon>
                More
            </button>
            <button ion-button color="primary" icon-start>
                <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
                Text
            </button>
            <button ion-button color="secondary" icon-start>
                <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
                Call
            </button>
       </ion-item-options>

    </ion-item-sliding>

</ion-list-header>
```

Comment: Great answer! And it would be even better if the OP defined a contact type (interface) so that the above code could use properties (such as `name` and `title`) instead of `contact[1]` and `contact[4]`. It would certainly make it more maintainable and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you, this worked flawlessly! And yes you are definitely correct @DeborahK, I will definitely take that into account as i'm building this app. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear that. You're welcome. @DeborahK: Thank you. This praise means a lot to me. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over your contacts with following changes

```
//<ion-item-sliding *ngFor ="let att of contactArray;  let idx = index">
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor ="let contact of contactArray[tagidx]">
```

`contact` is then the array for one contact

```
//<h2 id="name">{{att.h2}} {{contactArray[tagidx][idx][1] + ' ' + contactArray[tagidx][idx][3]}}</h2>
//<p id="company">{{att.p2}} {{contactArray[tagidx][idx][4]}}</p>
<h2 id="name">{{att.h2}} {{contact[1] + ' ' + contact[3]}}</h2>
<p id="company">{{att.p2}} {{contact[4]}}</p>
```